# MongoDB projection exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am trying to use projection in mongoDB using MongoRepository and get JsonParserException. Below is the code:

```
@Query(value= "{'regId': ?0, 'data': {$elemMatch: {'$OR': [{'sampleStep' :?1}, {'sampleStep' : {$gt: ?1}, raw: ?2}]}}, 'ts': ?2, 'regId': ?2}")

Data findAllById(ObjectId regId, String sampleStep, boolean flag);
```

Exception message:

```
 {'regId': ?0, 'data': {$elemMatch: {'$OR': [{'sampleStep' : "1000000000"}, {'sampleStep' : {$gt: "1000000000"}, raw: true}]}}, 'ts': true, 'regId': true}
      ^] with root cause com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'regId': ?0, 'data': {$elemMatch: {'$OR': [{'sampleStep' : "1000000000"}, {'sampleStep' : {$gt: "1000000000"}, raw: true}]}}, 'ts': true, 'regId': true}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the using of ? in the values.
For example, if you will replace:

```
{$gt: ?1}
```

with

```
{$gt: 1}
```

You will not have any exception.

I also think that the following should be removed:

```
'regId': ?0
```

Probably there is no **regId==0**. 
Here is an ObjectId example:

```
ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")
```

To read more about ObjectIds please follow the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/ObjectId/).